# condtion checking and function not calling in android

Tags: android

Here I am getting the image extension whether it is a jpg or png.if jpg means I am checking the condition by using if.If it is true means i want to call the downloadfromurl and download the image.

Now My problem if I am debugging the application fileNameWithoutExtn getting the value as jpg and iamge also jpg both are equal means i want to call the function it's not calling.

can anyone please help me.

**java class file**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_events_list_view);

        schedule_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();


        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String image = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getText().toString();


                //String[] str1 = image.split("/");
                //imagename = str1[5].trim();
            //String fileName = image.substring( image.lastIndexOf('/')+1, image.length() );
        String fileNameWithoutExtn = image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
            //String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/foo.txt");

        String image1="jpg";
        if(fileNameWithoutExtn==image1){

        task = (DownloadFileFromURL) new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(image);


        }



            }

        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetSchedule().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetSchedule extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MediaCoverage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    schedules = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SCHEDULES);

                    // looping through All Schdules
                    for (int i = 0; i < schedules.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = schedules.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        String place = c.getString(TAG_PLACE);
                        String datetime = c.getString(TAG_DATETIME);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object

                        // tmp hashmap for Schedule
                        HashMap<String, String> schedule_file = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_CONTENT, content);
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_PLACE, place);
                        schedule_file.put(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);

                        // adding schedule list
                        schedule_list.add(schedule_file);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MediaCoverage.this, schedule_list, 
                    R.layout.news_events_list_item, 
                    new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_CONTENT, TAG_IMAGE, TAG_PLACE, TAG_DATETIME }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.title,R.id.content, R.id.image, R.id.place, R.id.datetime });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_types:
            pDialogD = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialogD.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialogD.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialogD.setMax(100);
            pDialogD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            //pDialogD.setCancelable(true);
            pDialogD.show();
            return pDialogD;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static File getSaveFilePath(String fileName) {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Image");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, fileName);
        return file;
    }
    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar_types);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                conn.connect();             

                int lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();

                input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
               // String SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 

                file = new File(SDCardRoot, fileNameWithoutExtn);


                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;

                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialogD.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        protected void onPostExecute(String URL) {
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_types);          
            final String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+fileNameWithoutExtn;
            //String imagePath2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/school_calender.pdf";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed :"+imagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MediaCoverage.this, new String[] { file.toString() },  null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() { 

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + imagePath + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
            });

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

            //application/pdf

        }       
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {           
        if (conn != null)
        {   
            task.cancel(true);                      
        }                   
        finish();           
    }
}
```

**logcat errors**

```
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at com.politicalmileage.vel.MediaCoverage$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MediaCoverage.java:289)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at com.politicalmileage.vel.MediaCoverage$DownloadFileFromURL.onPostExecute(MediaCoverage.java:1)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-25 16:04:54.085: E/AndroidRuntime(13083):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: jyothi, are you getting fileNameWithoutExtn=jpg here?

Comment: yes pratik it's getting

Comment: if(fileNameWithoutExtn.equalsIgnoreCase(image1)){} try with this.

Comment: hi pratik i have a smll doubt in downloadfronurl function final String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+fileNameWithoutExtn;

Comment: can you send me your whole code to me?

Comment: can you please tell me above line right r wrong

Comment: the above one is full java code

Comment: its right, I need our whole project, so I could debug

Comment: You forgot the name of the file. fileNameWithoutExtn is just the extension right? So you're looking for "/sdcard/folder/jpg" which does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fileNameWithoutExtn.contains(image1)` instead of `"=="`.

```
if(fileNameWithoutExtn==image1){

    task = (DownloadFileFromURL) new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(image);

}
```

**Corrected**

```
if(fileNameWithoutExtn.contains(image1)){

    task = (DownloadFileFromURL) new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(image);

}
```

You also have String.equals or String.compareTo.

Comment: if(fileNameWithoutExtn.equals(image1.contains("jpg")))

Comment: You cannot compare a String with a boolean

Comment: Are you using fileNameWithoutExtn.contains(image1) ?

Comment: hi vte i posted my logcat error can u please tell me

Comment: Vte can you please tell me

Comment: Well the problem is in your DonwloadImageFromUrl class.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

`if(fileNameWithoutExtn==image1)`

by

`if(fileNameWithoutExtn.equalsIgnoreCase(image1))`  // if `fileNameWithoutExtn = jpg`

OR

`if(fileNameWithoutExtn.contains(image1))`   // if `fileNameWithoutExtn = something something.jpg`

Comment: hi Aniruddha i posted my logcat error can u please tell me

Comment: Point out the line number 289

Comment: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MediaCoverage.this, new String[] { file.toString() },  null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

Comment: the above line is 289 can you please tell me where i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

String[] strTemp = image.split(".");

```
                for(int i=0;i<strTemp.length;i++)
                {
                    Log.e("data is ", "strTemp[] is "+strTemp[i]);
                }


String fileNameWithoutExtn=strTemp[1];
```

and then use

```
if(fileNameWithoutExtn.equalsIgnoreCase(image1))
```

{
}